# Preview css @media screen (max-width) on bigger device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to preview specific `div` how it looks like in mobile.
The div HTML I get from external source. For example:

```
var external_html='<div>Responsive div</div>' +
   '<style>@media screen(max-width:360) {{color:blue}}</style>')
var element=$(external_html)
.appendTo(document.body)
```

Noe I want to see how it looks like on different devices. I'm doing `$(element).width(300)`, but it's still show's the desktop version.

**In Other Words:** I am searching to emulate screen size for CSS, but only for one element in the document.

*Just a note: I know that I can put the external_html in IFRAME, but I ate IFRAMES)*

---

## HTML Version of the question:

```
<div style=width:250px>
   It's will be black
</div>
<div style=width:190px>
   I hope to see it blue. But it still black
</div>

<style>
div.preview (max-width:200px){
   // I am want this style to be applied to tje second div only
   color:blue
}
</style>
```

**Why?** I am using Angular for creating a WYSIWYG directive.
I want the editor to support RESPONSIVE layout. I mean I want the end-user, to be able to see in real time, how I gonna looks like in mobile.
The problem is. How can I emulate a mobile device in the directive?
Thank's

Comment: _“but only for one element in the document”_ – why, to what end? Are you trying to debug stuff, or …? (And btw., you media query example is invalid, as it is missing any selector.)

Comment: Is this something for an end-user or local debug? If it's the latter, you might just be better off playing around with the CSS/HTML of your browser development console.

Comment: It's for WYSIWYG Editor for my end-user, that want to preview thier stuff

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't as its design could be affected by the surrounding/preceding/following elements etc. So trying to extract it from where it is will loose that context.

Comment: WHAT I Searched for and didn't know the name it's called: CSS ELEMENT QUERY (not media query) More Info: https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries    AND   https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers... So I have to solve it by myself.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khuj1ph5/2

I created a function called `addTo`:

```
function addTo(target,html,style,deviceWidth){
```

The parameters:

```
target -  that target DOM element
html   -  the html text, to append to the DOM
style  -  the CSS style, I would like to apply to the HTML
deviceWidth - the width of the device, I would like to see.
```

***How is it works?**

It parse the CSS, and make changes to `mediaText` so it will appear like in the original device.

Works for CSS responsive designs.

For example, this will show only the `on_small` message:

```
var my_size=300
var external_html='<div class=on_big>On Big</div><div class=on_small>On small</div>'
var external_style=' .on_big,.on_small{display:none} @media   (min-width:500px) {.on_big{display:block;}} @media   (max-width:500px) {.on_small{display:block;}}'

addTo(document.body,external_html,external_style,my_size)
```

**The Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/khuj1ph5/2

For testing: Just change the my_size from 300 to 600.